# Angular Nested @ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, viewchild

I got a component which is dealing with a form. One of its attributes is the following:

```
@ViewChild('name') name: ElementRef;
```

`name` comes from a reference in the form itself:

```
<input type="text" #name>
```

At the bottom of the form I have a submit button:

```
<button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
...
onAdd() {
  // Do something with this.name.nativeElement.value;
}
```

With just one attribute that's fine, but is it possible to wrap in an object (or an interface?) these `@ViewChild`s so they are all packed together instead of loose in the component? Something like one of these:

```
person: {
  @ViewChild('name') name: ElementRef;
}

Interface Person {
  @ViewChild('name') name: ElementRef;
}
```

I made a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/carlosromerob/pen/Yzpprzm).

Comment: You want to group them just for readability purposes? Use comments maybe?

Comment: @Julius To deal with just a single object and pass on that single thing somewhere else - through EventEmitter, for example.

Comment: So you can create a function which will collect all that to an object